# Goto particular path when push notification arrives (Angular, Ionic, ngcordova)

Tags: android, angularjs, push-notification, ionic-framework

Consider this scenario. I have an ionic / angular app and I am using the the ngcordova plugin for push notifications. Now let us say a push notification arrives when the app is in the background. User, views the notification in the App drawer and then clicks the notification for further information. I would like the user to navigate to a particular path using $location.path(). How can I tap into the notification click event?

Comment: Have you tried listening for the received event? $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', func(event, notification))

Comment: Sure. But, this event is only to capture the event when notification arrives. My problem: How do I capture the event corresponding to click of notification in notification drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Turns out that there is no need to tap into the notification click event. 
You could check if the app is in foreground using:

```
notification.foreground
```

so, if

```
if(notification.foreground) {
  //do something for the case where user is using the app.
  $popup('A notification just arrived');
} else {
  //do something for the case where user is not using the app.
  $location.path('/tab/somepage');
}
```

Comment: How could I implement this dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you elaborate @KaranSofat?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question some days ago. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281334/151689)

What i did was when the notification arrives to the app i save some data from the playload to the *localStorage* and then in the *resume* event of the app i read this var from *localStorage* and change the state of the app and passing this var to the url i want.

When the app is in the background and receive the notification you can save the playload to the *localStorage*:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
   if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() && notification.event == 'message') {
        var newsid=notification.payload.newsid;
        if (typeof newsid != 'undefined') {
            // save the newsid to read it later in the resume event
            $window.localStorage.setItem('goafterpush',newsid);
        }
    }
});
```

And then in the *resume* event you can read the previous saved playload and use that data to change the state of the app and redirect to another route:

```
$ionicPlatform.on("resume",function(event){
     // read the newsid saved previously when received the notification
     var goafterpush=$window.localStorage.getItem('goafterpush');
     if (goafterpush) {
         $window.localStorage.removeItem('goafterpush');
         $state.go('app.newsdetail',{id:goafterpush});
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be done if you are using phonegap-plugin-push.

Refer the [blog article from here](http://blog.nawaratne.com/2016/04/cordova-push-notification-identify-app.html).

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    if(data.additionalData.foreground){
        //Do stuff you want to do if app is running on foreground while push notification received
    }else{
        //Do stuff you want to do if the app is running on background while the push notification received
    }
});
```