# android push notification in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing mobile app using ionic framework.I have Successfully implemented push notification.When I click on the notification I want it should go on particular page.How will I do this?
In Client Side:

```
 var user = $ionicUser.get();
     if(!user.user_id) {
     // Set your user_id here, or generate a random one.
     user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
     };


     // Identify your user with the Ionic User Service
     $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function(){
     //$scope.identified = true;
     //alert('User ID ' + user.user_id);
     //alert("here");
     $ionicPush.register({
      canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
      canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
      canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
      canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
      onNotification: function(notification) {

        // Handle new push notifications here
        // console.log(notification);
        return true;
      }
     });
     });



  });
})

.config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
  $ionicAppProvider.identify({
    app_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    dev_push: false
  });
}])
```

In Server Side I have used php:

```
$deviceToken = 'APA91bHKwBKrIjmmZ9lke97fl_GbOQ9iRRo-S2sNnZp085hPqVaTHMOd0wqhYFF1PtrtOzFrETX7ZNIkU0JDhC49Tby_AEFIQFRX99B0QpZd7xdiTqsP6sZ08P-8ESdJAie5AJNxhW89nQ7S9evZNcAc9tsJaG91Xw';

$registrationIds = explode(",",$deviceToken);

//$registrationIds = array($deviceToken);

// prep the bundle

$msg = array

(

    'notId' => time(),

    'message'       => 'Technovault is awesome!!!',

    'title'         => 'Title',

    'smallIcon'     =>'icon'



);

$fields = array

(

    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,

    'data'              => $msg

);

$headers = array

(

    'Authorization: key=' . 'xxxxxxxxxx',

    'Content-Type: application/json'

);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

$result = curl_exec($ch );

curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;

}

else {

    echo "Error";

}
```

Comment: Please update your question with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notification` you receive on client side has parameter `foreground` associated. It's value will be `false` when you come to application from clicking notification. So this is how you can perform specific action:

```
onNotification: function(notification) {
                  if(notification.foreground == false){
                    //add your logic here to navigate to other page
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Hi, I still do not know the solution...I am using node server and I put the payload like so in my server: "notification": { "alert": message.message,"ios": {"badge":1,"payload": {"taskId": message.relatedTask } }, But I don't know how in my client to read my taskId payload. How will you read the payload in the onNotification callback?

Comment: @HughHou if you are using deprecated older plugin  then you can acces taskId on client side on notification object this way `notification.payload.taskId` . But if you are using latest plugin then `notification.additionalData.taskId` .

Answer (score 0):

I resolve a similar situation some days ago. I've an app with articles list and article details. When there is a new article the server send a notification than include the article id in the playload.

When the app receive the notification, i save it in the localStorage and when the user click on the notification, with the *resume* event i can read this localStorage item and change the state of the app and show the article controller view for this article id.

I haven't used the *ionPush* library, i used the Cordova *PushPlugin* because i have a custom push notification server.

When the app received the notification:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
   if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() && notification.event == 'message') {
        var newsid=notification.payload.newsid;
        if (typeof newsid != 'undefined') {
            // save the newsid to read it later in the resume event
            $window.localStorage.setItem('goafterpush',newsid);
        }
    }
});
```

And the *resume* event:

```
$ionicPlatform.on("resume",function(event){
     // read the newsid saved previously when received the notification
     var goafterpush=$window.localStorage.getItem('goafterpush');
     if (goafterpush) {
         $window.localStorage.removeItem('goafterpush');
         $state.go('app.newsdetail',{id:goafterpush});
     }
});
```

I hope this code can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've this working for Android and iOS, in python I've set payload with the state name and Id parameter

```
payload = {"$state":"state.name", "$stateParams": "{\"id\": \""+time()+"\"}"}
```

Then I include it with all the other message stuff

```
"payload": payload
```

This should happen inside your $msg array, and that's it, when the user clicks the notification your app opens and goes to the defined state using the provided parameter.